# AngularJS - how to add javascript dependency in Directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directives and while I call that directives, I need to load my JS first. Is there anyway to inject Javascript directly into Directives of angularjs?

Here is the code.

var directive = module.exports = function($rootScope, $location, service, user) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function () {
            $rootScope.$on( '$routeChangeSuccess', function(event,current) {
                var path = $location.path();
                var pageName = current.$$route.title ? current.$$route.title : path;
                if(!current.redirectTo) {
                    user.then(function(userInfo) {
                    service.method(pageName, {
                        marketName: userInfo.marketName,
                        accountName: userInfo.name,
                        clientServices: userInfo.isClientServices(),
                        userType: userInfo.type
                        });
                    });
                }
            }); 
        }
    };
};

directive.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', 'service', 'user'];

Please do needful.

Comment: Can you please give an tiny example?
Because, if it is plain JS, you just copy it inside the directive's controller

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can bundle a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) with js code (like web components), the js has to be included outside of the directive. You can however use angularjs dependency injection to inject the included angular services to your directive:

```
app.factory('myDependency', function() {
  var myDependencyInstance;
  return myDependencyInstance;
});

app.directive('directive', ['myDependency', function(myDependency) {
     return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
    };
}])
```

But I guess its not what you want. You could bundle js into the directive's template, but then the js code would be duplicated every time you add the directive and this would propably only work with non angular js code.